# Unexpected behaviour of border: * no_line

Tags: python, xlwt

I am trying to create cells without borders, but somehow that default thin border is always there.

```python
from xlwt import Workbook,easyxf

tl = easyxf('border: top thick, right no_line, bottom no_line, left thick')
tr = easyxf('border: top thick, right thick, bottom no_line, left no_line')
br = easyxf('border: top no_line, right thick, bottom thick, left no_line')
bl = easyxf('border: top no_line, right no_line, bottom thick, left thick')

w = Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet('Border')

ws.write(1, 1, style=tl)
ws.write(1, 2, style=tr)
ws.write(2, 1, style=bl)
ws.write(2, 2, style=br)

w.save('borders-test.xls')
```

What I get is

[image: Result]

However I would expect (no thin borders within thick borders)

[image: Expectation]

I am looking for the solution to make `no_line` work as expected (or to understand that it is actually some different thing and adjust my expectations). I am however not looking for workarounds like "set color of border the same as background" (unless it is known that GUIs work the very same way).

```
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin

xlwt==1.1.2
```

p.s. Simply removing `... no_line` parts from code (as it is default) does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use top_color *color* , bottom_color *color* , left_color *color* , right_color *color* which in your case it should be white.

Where ever you dont want border for example in **tl** you dont want border at right and bottom so set right_color white, bottom_color white.

```
   from xlwt import Workbook,easyxf

   tl = easyxf('border: top thick, bottom thick, left thick, right thick,
                right_color white, bottom_color white')
   tr = easyxf('border: top thick, bottom thick, left thick, right thick,
                left_color white,  bottom_color white')
   br = easyxf('border: top thick, bottom thick, left thick, right thick,
                left_color white,  top_color white')
   bl = easyxf('border: top thick, bottom thick, left thick, right thick,
                right_color white, top_color white')
   w = Workbook()
   ws = w.add_sheet('Border')

   ws.write(1, 1, style=tl)
   ws.write(1, 2, style=tr)
   ws.write(2, 1, style=bl)
   ws.write(2, 2, style=br)

   w.save('borders-test.xls')
```

Hope this solves your problem.